# Navigation last next for own automated labels

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, automation, links

I would like to add some navigation to my PDFs, such as jumping from change note to change note or todo note to todo note or such to the next such and back, something like

```
\newcounter{cnt:todo}
\newcommand{\todo}{
\stepcounter{cnt:todo}
\marginpar[
    \centering\label{todo:cnt:todo}
        \hyperref[todo:cnt:todo-1]{$\Leftarrow$}
        \normalsize{$\bigstar$}\xspace\index{todo}
        \hyperref[todo:cnt:todo+1]{$\Rightarrow$}
    ]{
    \centering\label{todo:cnt:todo}
        \hyperref[todo:cnt:todo-1]{$\Leftarrow$}
        \normalsize{$\bigstar$}\xspace\index{todo}
        \hyperref[todo:cnt:todo+1]{$\Rightarrow$}
    }
\xspace
}
```

Sorry for the pseudocode but I am asking because I am clueless and I guess those who can answer the question will be used to pseudocode drafting ideas anyways

All hints pointing me into the direction I need to read up welcome, all solutions most welcome of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to place labels following a `\refstepcounter` and extracting the hyper anchor with `\getrefbykeydefault` (from `refcount` package, being loaded by `hyperref` anyway.)

The label is automatically generated from the counter value and then `\@ifundefined{r@....}{}{}` is applied in order to check whether the label exists already or not -- this will prevent messages. (Side note: The label `foo` is stored in a macro named `\r@foo`)

The code for left/right pages is the equal, so I wrapped a macro around it and call it inside the `\ToDo` command.

Please compile at least twice!

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{todocntr}



\makeatletter

\newcommand{\navcommoncode}{%
  \centering
  \label{todo:\number\value{todocntr}}%
  \@ifundefined{r@todo:\the\numexpr\number\value{todocntr}-1}{%
  }{%
    \hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{todo:\the\numexpr\number\value{todocntr}-1}{anchor}{0}}{$\Leftarrow$}
  }%
  {\normalsize\quad$\bigstar$}\quad\index{todo}%
  \@ifundefined{r@todo:\the\numexpr\number\value{todocntr}+1}{%
  }{%
    \hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{todo:\the\numexpr\number\value{todocntr}+1}{anchor}{0}}{$\Rightarrow$}
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\ToDo}{%
    \refstepcounter{todocntr}%
    \marginpar[%
    \navcommoncode%
  ]{%
    \navcommoncode%
  }%
}


\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\blindtext

\ToDo

\blindtext[3]
\ToDo

\blindtext[20]
\ToDo

Foo \ToDo

\blindtext[50]
\ToDo


\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah! Works. And I am able to make my different environments from it. Now the question is only if I should try to understand what I am doing... Guess I should...

thx a lot!

Comment: @ErikItter: If you have questions about the solution just ask...